# How to trigger ahk script in remote system using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, autohotkey, remote-access

I was trying to trigger an ahk script in remote system with windows operating system. When I trigger it locally in the remote system (using cygwin), I am able to trigger the ahk script.

```
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey.exe ./test.ahk
```

But when I try to execute the same command through ssh from a linux machine, ahk file is not getting triggered.

```
ssh Administrator@xx.xx.xx.xx
Administrator@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey.exe ./test.ahk
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Did you cd into the directory of the test.ahk file?

Comment: Yes, I am executing the command in the folder where I have test.ahk file

Comment: Can you run other programs or is this specific to AutoHotkey? What happens when you compile the script and try to execute the resulting exe file via ssh?

Comment: I have compiled the ahk file to exe and tried, but still no luck. Actually I am opening a program in windows and enter some series of inputs to the program and closing it, which I couldnt do through ssh. So I am using ahk to get this task executed locally. It is not working either for ahk file or compiled exe file

Comment: So apparently you cannot run any program through ssh, is that correct?

Comment: Looks like that is my situation now... Any Idea how to run a program in remote system through ssh?